# What is the recommended read timout on serial port running 9600 baud?

Tags: c#, serial-port, serial-communication

I'm running a protocol over a serial port (RS232)
I've read timeout set to 2200 ms on start and then I set it to 55, but now and then I still get read timeout.

What would be the recommended timeout settings running a 9600 baud connection ?

Comment: Aim high then tune it down. If you can find out what is causing the longer bursts, try optimizing those.

Comment: I would never use a timeout!!!  With serial ports always use Async Read methods to insure you get correct results.  Sync methods never work with the Microsoft driver unless you use very slow baud rates. Been having issues with Microsoft drives since my 1st x86 PC in 1982.